# Javascript - Function that counts, how many correct answers there are

Tags: javascript, function, validation

I've been trying to make a function that counts the number of correct answers. I've been able to make a function that validates whether the different students have answered correctly in that particular order, but it doesn't count the number of correct answers.

Another thing I've been trying to do is, if the students have the same amount of correct answers, it has sort them alphabetically.

I will greatly appreciate the help.

---

```
function validation(student, answers){

    if(answers.includes("ABCABCABC")){

      return student + " got" + " " + answers;
        
    }else{         
    }
}
```

console.log(validation(" Simon", ["ABCABC"]))

Comment: this is a duplicate question, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939562/how-to-count-the-number-of-correct-answers-using-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of correct answers using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939562/how-to-count-the-number-of-correct-answers-using-javascript)